# How do I get the local IP address in Go?

Tags: go

I want to get the computer's IP address. I used the code below, but it returns `127.0.0.1`.

I want to get the IP address, such as `10.32.10.111`, instead of the loopback address.

```
name, err := os.Hostname()
if err != nil {
     fmt.Printf("Oops: %v\n", err)
     return
}

addrs, err := net.LookupHost(name)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Oops: %v\n", err)
    return
}

for _, a := range addrs {
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You need to loop through all network interfaces

```
ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
// handle err
for _, i := range ifaces {
    addrs, err := i.Addrs()
    // handle err
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        var ip net.IP
        switch v := addr.(type) {
        case *net.IPNet:
                ip = v.IP
        case *net.IPAddr:
                ip = v.IP
        }
        // process IP address
    }
}
```

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/BDt3qEQ_2H) (taken from util/helper.go)

Comment: Thanks, added it to the answer

Comment: util/helper.go is probably this https://code.google.com/p/whispering-gophers/source/browse/util/helper.go . What about IPv6? This only seems to work for IPv4 Addresses.

Comment: The call to net.Interfaces() returns no error and 0 interfaces on my Linux host (Manjaro, current) https://play.golang.org/p/0K5bL_eqFm
:(

Answer (score 191):

Here is a better solution to retrieve the preferred outbound ip address when there are multiple ip interfaces exist on the machine.

```
import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

// Get preferred outbound ip of this machine
func GetOutboundIP() net.IP {
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:80")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    localAddr := conn.LocalAddr().(*net.UDPAddr)

    return localAddr.IP
}
```

Comment: I was searching for the same and this is only one that worked fine for me :) , By the way i wanted to know why you are doing udp connection to Google Dns and whats the value whole of "conn.LocalAddr().String()" ?

Comment: Actually it does not establish any connection and the destination does not need to be existed at all :)  So, what the code does actually, is to get the local up address if it would connect to that target, you can change to any other IP address you want.   `conn.LocalAddr().String()` is the local ip and port.

Comment: This is better than the accepted solution.  Even if you have 2 IP addresses on the subnet of the default route's gateway (say a wired and wireless IP), this (for me) is picking the default IP that traffic will use.

Comment: Wait what? Why does `Dial` "not establish any connection". According to the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial) "Dial connects to the address on the named network." How is this working? Does Dial connect or not?

Comment: @darkwing  it is using the udp protocol,  unlike TCP,  it does not have handshake nor a connection.  hence,  the target does not need be there and you will receive the outbound IP.

Comment: @darkwing: See it as a "logical" connection, not a "physical" one.

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor Does this needs be "8.8.8.8:53" instead of "8.8.8.8:80" ?

Comment: @SanketSudake  any port number is ok.   there is no connection established

Comment: Is there a way to get the local IP back in CIDR notation?  I found various examples using DefaultMask but not the actual mask.

Answer (score 49):

To ensure that you get a non-loopback address, simply check that an IP is not a loopback when you are iterating.

```
// GetLocalIP returns the non loopback local IP of the host
func GetLocalIP() string {
    addrs, err := net.InterfaceAddrs()
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    for _, address := range addrs {
        // check the address type and if it is not a loopback the display it
        if ipnet, ok := address.(*net.IPNet); ok && !ipnet.IP.IsLoopback() {
            if ipnet.IP.To4() != nil {
                return ipnet.IP.String()
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution as long as there is only one non-loopback interface available.

Answer (score 26):

`net.LookupHost()` on your `os.Hostname()` is probably always going to give you 127.0.0.1, because that's what's in your `/etc/hosts` or equivalent.

I think what you want to use is [`net.InterfaceAddrs()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#InterfaceAddrs):

> `func InterfaceAddrs() ([]Addr, error)`
>
> InterfaceAddrs returns a list of the system's network interface addresses.

Comment: This has its own wrinkles. The addresses are provided as strings. Given an IP address (specific Go type, not the generic term) there is no direct comparison. It is either necessary to convert the IP to a string and compare or parse the strings to get the IP to compare, neither of which looks trivial to this neophyte Go programmer. I'm looking for library procedures to convert the string to an IP but have not yet found one.

Comment: What is the IP address Go type you refer to?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP

     type IP []byte

And the parser I seek is just below that on the page:

     func ParseCIDR(s string) (IP, *IPNet, error)

(Cannot seem to format those lines as code.)

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
host, _ := os.Hostname()
addrs, _ := net.LookupIP(host)
for _, addr := range addrs {
    if ipv4 := addr.To4(); ipv4 != nil {
        fmt.Println("IPv4: ", ipv4)
    }   
}
```

Unlike the poster's example, it returns only non-loopback addresses, e.g. 10.120.X.X.

Comment: but if i use if loop it will be local inside that loop... i want to use the ipv4 value outside this loop

Comment: @VijayKumar, `var ipv4 net.IP` outside of the loop and use `ipv4 = addr.To4()` (instead of `ipv4 := addr.To4()`

Answer (score 4):

```
func GetInternalIP() string {
    itf, _ := net.InterfaceByName("enp1s0") //here your interface
    item, _ := itf.Addrs()
    var ip net.IP
    for _, addr := range item {
        switch v := addr.(type) {
        case *net.IPNet:
            if !v.IP.IsLoopback() {
                if v.IP.To4() != nil {//Verify if IP is IPV4
                    ip = v.IP
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ip != nil {
        return ip.String()
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func resolveHostIp() (string) {

    netInterfaceAddresses, err := net.InterfaceAddrs()

    if err != nil { return "" }

    for _, netInterfaceAddress := range netInterfaceAddresses {

        networkIp, ok := netInterfaceAddress.(*net.IPNet)

        if ok && !networkIp.IP.IsLoopback() && networkIp.IP.To4() != nil {

            ip := networkIp.IP.String()

            fmt.Println("Resolved Host IP: " + ip)

            return ip
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one IP address except 127.0.0.1, You can check the code down here.

```
conn,err := net.Dial("ip:icmp","google.com")
fmt.Println(conn.LocalAddr())
```

The second parameter can be any IP address except 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you elaborate how this is different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37382208/916440 ? Thanks.

Comment: This code should `Close()` the returned connection (if no error) to ensure the underlying file descriptor gets closed.

Comment: @KamilDziedzic The difference is the protocol. For this function, I think it is better to use UDP.

Comment: @lionello Yes. If you really want to use it, you should add ```defer ...``` in this function.

Answer (score -2):

```
var (
    ret    net.IP
    err    error
    ifaces []net.Interface
    addrs  []net.Addr
)
if ifaces, err = net.Interfaces(); err == nil {
    for _, i := range ifaces {
        if addrs, err = i.Addrs(); err == nil {
            for _, a := range addrs {
                if ipnet, ok := a.(*net.IPNet); ok {
                    if ipv4 := ipnet.IP.To4(); ipv4 != nil {
                        if ipv4.IsGlobalUnicast() {
                            ret = ipv4
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return ret
```

Works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).