# How to know a Pod's own IP address from inside a container in the Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes assigns an IP address for each container, but how can I acquire the IP address from a container in the Pod? I couldn't find the way from documentations.

Edit: I'm going to run Aerospike cluster in Kubernetes. and the config files need its own IP address. And I'm attempting to use confd to set the hostname. I would use the environment variable if it was set.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

The simplest answer is to ensure that your pod or replication controller yaml/json files add the pod IP as an environment variable by adding the config block defined below. (the block below additionally makes the name and namespace available to the pod)

```
env:
- name: MY_POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
- name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
- name: MY_POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP
```

Recreate the pod/rc and then try

```
echo $MY_POD_IP
```

also run `env` to see what else kubernetes provides you with.

Comment: I've just tested your solution, and it works super fine. I'm 100% sure kubernetes doesn't have such an environment variable, because `printenv | grep '10.254.24.167'` doesn't return anything except the user defined variable MY_POD_IP. Anyway, take my vote sir :)

Comment: Have you ever tried to fetch the IP of the host through `status.hostIP`?

Comment: @PEdroArthur No I have not, afaik it is a recent addition. See the pull request here - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/42717

Comment: This is called "Downwad API": https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api

Comment: Thank you very much , this answer really make me a big faver.

Comment: For a future-safer option, `status.podIPs` can be used, which will inject a comma-separated list of IP addresses (such as IPv4 and IPv6 on a dual-stack pod)

Comment: Thanks,  What if I have 3 replicas (instances) running and want to know the IP of each container.

Answer (score 43):

**Some clarifications** (not really an answer)

In kubernetes, every pod gets assigned an IP address, and every container in the pod gets assigned that same IP address. Thus, as Alex Robinson stated in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30747311/3037171), you can just use `hostname -i` inside your container to get the pod IP address.

I tested with a pod running two dumb containers, and indeed `hostname -i` was outputting the same IP address inside both containers. Furthermore, that IP was equivalent to the one obtained using `kubectl describe pod` from outside, which validates the whole thing IMO.

However, [PiersyP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418819/3037171) seems more clean to me.

## Sources

From [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/#resource-sharing-and-communication):

> The applications in a pod all use the same network namespace (same IP and port space), and can thus “find” each other and communicate using localhost. Because of this, applications in a pod must coordinate their usage of ports. Each pod has an IP address in a flat shared networking space that has full communication with other physical computers and pods across the network.

Another piece from [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#kubernetes-model):

> Until now this document has talked about containers. In reality, Kubernetes applies IP addresses at the Pod scope - containers within a Pod share their network namespaces - including their IP address. This means that containers within a Pod can all reach each other’s ports on localhost.

Answer (score 34):

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

Give you a list of pods with name, status, ip, node...

Comment: and if you need the expose IP you can do **kubectl get services**

Comment: Lol, I am trying all sorts of awk and sed but this was much simpler with just a grep.

Answer (score 29):

`kubectl describe pods <name of pod>` will give you some information including the IP

Comment: I think the question is about getting the IP from inside the pod/container, where `kubectl` isn't available.

Answer (score 19):

```
POD_HOST=$(kubectl get pod $POD_NAME --template={{.status.podIP}})
```

This command will return you an IP

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know the IP address in a container in a Pod. So I want to know it without using `kubectl`.

Answer (score 15):

The container's IP address should be properly configured inside of its network namespace, so any of the standard linux tools can get it. For example, try `ifconfig`, `ip addr show`, `hostname -I`, etc. from an attached shell within one of your containers to test it out.

Answer (score 12):

You could use

```
kubectl describe pod `hostname` | grep IP | sed -E 's/IP:[[:space:]]+//'
```

which is based on what @mibbit suggested.

This takes the following facts into account:

- hostname is set to POD's name but [this might change in the future](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4825)
- `kubectl` was manually placed in the container (possibly when the image was built)
- Kubernetes provides a service account credential to the container implicitly as described in [Accessing the Cluster / Accessing the API from a Pod](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster.html#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod), i.e. `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` in the container

Comment: Don't pipe `grep` to `sed`: `kubectl describe pod $POD | sed -nE '/IP/s/IP:[[:space:]]+//p'`  (but awk is better for this than sed)

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler to remember than the `sed` approach is to use `awk`.

Here is an example, which you can run on your local machine:

```
kubectl describe pod `<podName>` | grep IP | awk '{print $2}'
```

The IP itself is on column 2 of the output, hence `$2` .

Comment: I assume it's because you're not answering the question. The questions is `but how can I acquire the IP address from a container in the Pod?`

You're assuming the person in question has access to `kubectl` on the pod itself.

Comment: Don't pipe grep to awk: `kubectl describe pod $POD | awk '/IP/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, instead of relying on downward API, programmatically reading the local IP address (from network interfaces) from inside of the container also works.

For example, in golang:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551220/6247478

Comment: Is this the GO equivalent of doing `hostname -i` and taking the first ipv4 address that isn't loopback?

Answer (score -1):

Containers have the same IP with the pod they are in.

So from inside the container you can just do `ip a` and the IP you get is the one the pod has also.