# how does spring boot connect localhost mysql in k8s?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm new to k8s, using docker-mac-desktop k8s test spring boot app.

I'm can connect success when spring boot in local connect mysql.

transform to docker k8s can not connected.

error is:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
```

is is local listening port:

```
redis-ser  2008    f    6u  IPv4 0x135c39363e412e7f      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6379 (LISTEN)
kubectl    2909    f    7u  IPv4 0x135c39365cf8a6ff      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8500 (LISTEN)
kubectl    2909    f    8u  IPv6 0x135c39365e7fb2cf      0t0  TCP [::1]:8500 (LISTEN)
mysqld     4091    f   28u  IPv4 0x135c39364db92abf      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
mysqld     4091    f   32u  IPv4 0x135c39364dc7e6ff      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:33060 (LISTEN)
com.docke 41823    f   20u  IPv4 0x135c39365b9a4d1f      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6443 (LISTEN)
com.docke 41823    f   25u  IPv6 0x135c39365e7f9a4f      0t0  TCP *:32003 (LISTEN)
com.docke 41926    f    8u  IPv4 0x135c393660b3785f      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:60701 (LISTEN)
```

spring boot database config:

```
spring:
datasource:
url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/foo
# mysqldb.default.svc.cluster.local tried
#
driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
username: f
```

spring boot pod.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: user-service
  labels:
    app: user-service
spec:
  containers:
    - name: user-service
      image: user_service:v1
```

map database ref: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services

mysql_svc.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: mysqldb
spec:
ports:
    - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306

---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: mysqldb
subsets:
- addresses:
    - ip: 192.168.0.101
    ports:
    - port: 3306
```

while the ip is come from `ifconfig`

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    inet6 fe80::c2c:cc27:8121:fbac%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5 
    inet 192.168.0.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

how can connect from k8s pod connect localhost database? :)

Comment: where is the database running and where is the Kubernetes running?

Comment: Where is your 192.168.0.101 located?  Check if that is accessible form your cluster.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu both database and Kubernetes is local pc

Comment: @Ajeet47 I'm network is home.  I'm see cluster and local is not same network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm solved this issue.

changed mysql_svc.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: mysqldb
spec:
type: ExternalName
externalName: host.docker.internal
ports:
    - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
```

map local port

change datasource config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb/foo
```

then connect success.

ref [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289009/during-local-development-with-kubernetes-minikube-how-should-i-connect-to-postg?rq=1)

Comment: is `mysqldb` the ipaddress:port in the `spring.datasource.url`? I have a similar issue, i try you suggestion but it didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682733/access-internal-database-in-cluster-with-local-application