# Access host resources from a kubernetes cluster service when minikube started with DOCKER vm driver

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have been able to successfully provision services inside a kubernetes minikube cluster to connect to services such as cassandra, kafka, etc installed on the host machine so far when I started the minikube cluster with the virutalbox vm.

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

For this I had to defined k8s manifest say fror cassandra endpoint with an IP address of the host machine identified from within the minikube cluster via following command as suggested [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/):

```
minikube ssh "route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
```

But when I start the minikube cluster with docker as VM driver, I am not able to figure out the ip address of the host machine as identified from inside the cluster because the command to fetch the same doesn't work.

```
minikube start --driver=docker

minikube ssh "route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
bash: route: command not found
```

Please suggest how could this ip address be retrived?

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicate things when it is not needed.
Since you want to run a testing environment (minikube suggests that) you should always want to start minikube with:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

Now the IP address of the Kubernetes cluster can be found simply by typing:

```
minikube ip
```

Or:

```
kubectl cluster-info | grep master
```

This command will show you the ip address that Kubernetes is running from, and the port (usually 6443).

Comment: Seems like I wasn't able to communicate the issue correctly. I don't want to know the ip address of the minikube cluster. I want to know the bridge ip address. Please see this: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/#getting-the-bridge-ip

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to it that way while using Docker as a driver due to the limitations of Docker VM.

There is a workaround listed [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds), saying:

> I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST
>
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
>   access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
>   special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal
>   IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will
>   not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for
>   Mac.
>
> The gateway is also reachable as gateway.docker.internal.

But there is no official analogical way to do so with Minikube.

I know that it might not be the exact thing you wanted but I see three options as a workaround:

- Use a different [driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/).
- Try using [Telepresence](https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence#telepresence-fast-realistic-local-development-for-kubernetes-microservices) as a proxy.
- Try [Routing an internal Kubernetes IP address to the host system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43326825/11560878).

I hope it helps.

Comment: There seems to be a solution. Please see this: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2735#issuecomment-638332820

Comment: @ShivamKapoor Yes, it might be helpful but there are still some unresolved issues with it. Have you managed to make it work in any of the given ways?