# How to know a Pod_A's PortIP address from another a container_b in the Pod_B?

Tags: kubernetes

**Example**:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP                NODE
test         pod_A       1/1       Running       1      17d   192.168.1.171     10-0-0-171.master
test         pod_B       1/1       Running       1      17d   192.168.1.172     10-0-0-172.node
```

By using:

```
kubectl exec -it pod_B --namespace=test -- sh
```

I can get a shell into the container_b that is running in my pod_B.

But, how can I get the Pod_A's PortIP address of "192.168.1.171" when I am in the shell of container_b?

There is a **similar** question, [How to know a Pod's own IP address from a container in the Pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30746888/6355684), and some official documents like [Exposing Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) and 
[Exposing Pod Information to Containers Using a DownwardApiVolumeFile](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/). *But those can not solve my problem.*

-----------UPDATE-----------

Recently, I fixed it by using K8s apiserver. In container_b of Pod_B, I can get a JSON response from `http://k8s_apiserver:port/api/v1/pods`, parse it, and get the PortIp of Pod_A at end. **BUT, is there any easier way to deal with it?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kube-dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) for service-discovery between your pods.

When you create a service for your pod `pod_A` with the name `service_A` the service will it's own IP address which points to your pod address. The service will also get a dns name like `service_A.service.default.cluster.local`. When you want to communicate from your `pod_B` to `pod_A` you now use the dns name and don't have to worry about the ip address from `pod_A` anymore.

Comment: Thanks and I can get your points clearly. But, in fact, I had deployed a **Redis cluster** by using the command:`redis-trib.rb create -- replicas 1 host1:port1 ... hostN:portN` Then there is a service in container_B of pod_B connecting that redis cluster to read and write the values. 

That is the reason why I need to get the **PortIP** of pod_A(redis cluster).

Comment: I also need to get podB's ip addresss in podA.  Do you find the solution for this?  Use environment variable or else?  Let me know if you have the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, I got the solution using service (environment variable and dns).         
  Here is  the reference: [kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)  


For example, the Service "redis-master" which exposes TCP port 6379 and has been allocated cluster IP address 10.0.0.11. 

REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST=10.0.0.11  

REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_PORT=6379

Comment: @HuaZhang Using environment variable and DNS, is a statical idea to deal with this problem, but not a dynamical one. After the service **restarted**, like the service of "Redis-Master" stoped and then restarted, the IP address had changed from `10.0.0.11` to `10.0.0.21`, you must fix the ENV_values manually.

If you want to change those ENV_values by themselves, you can get the IP address by using **the Kubernetes API**, while obviously, the cluster of Kubernetets has itself own service of "Kubernetes".