# In a Kubernetes cluster is it possible to obtain a container/pod IP address from inside a different container

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to determine the neighbour container or pod IP address, e.g. given its name? More specifically, if I have two running containers/pods C1 (ip=1.2.3.4) and C2 (ip=5.6.7.8) and I execute:

```
  ME$ kubectl exec -it C1 bash
  C1$ magic_command_to_get_ip C2
  5.6.7.8
```

Is there a magic_command_to_get_ip?

I am new to Kubernetes and I used to resolve names to addresses in Docker using `getent hosts tasks.$SERVICE`, but apparently it does not work with KB.

Answer (score 1):

Each pod has a service account mounted to it.

You can check that with

```
kubectl decsribe pod pod_name
```

**Output:**

```
Mounts:
/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from xxxxx-token-xxx (ro)
```

The command suggested by Raunak should work if your service account has permission to execute that command.

Please make sure the service account you are using has permission to run that command.

The error stated in comments **(Forbidden): pods "cassandra-0" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default"**  is beacuse of that.

More about service accounts [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this thread - [How to know a Pod's own IP address from inside a container in the Pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746888/how-to-know-a-pods-own-ip-address-from-inside-a-container-in-the-pod)

While you can use the `POD_HOST=$(kubectl get pod $POD_NAME --template={{.status.podIP}})` where your bash_variable can be an enum of all available pods in the cluster.

Comment: This requires having kubectl installed inside each container, correct?

Comment: I don't agree that this is not a duplicate, as I am trying to determine the neighbours IP and not its own

Comment: kubectl is a control utility to work with a k8s cluster as a whole and not limited to pods. It is used to communicate with the API server of the cluster and hence is not required to be installed in every pod

Comment: Well, I am trying to achieve the neighbours ip *from inside a container*. I installed Kubectl inside a container and still the command does not work: Error from server (Forbidden): pods "cassandra-0" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"